# in Wso2 Publisher Each user just access to himself API And Can't see other api

Tags: wso2, api-manager, apim

I use wso2 version 2.6.0
I have a wso2 publisher and have 3 users
I want each user see own api and user can't change other api for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide role-based access to the APIs you are creating.
Create 3 different roles [1] with required permissions from the carbon management console and assign those roles to the 3 users. Then configure those roles to the APIs you are creating.
Refer to this [2] to configure role-based access control in APIM.

For example:

- Create roles of `role1`, `role2`, and `role3` and assign them to the `user1`, `user2`, and `user3` respectively [1]. (Assign the necessary creator and publisher permissions for the corresponding roles)
- Then create 3 APIs of `api1`, `api2`, and `api3` using `user1`, `user2`, and `user3` respectively.
- Assign roles of `role1`, `role2`, and `role3` to `api1`, `api2`, and `api3` respectively using [2].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+User+Roles

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Enabling+Access+Control+Support+for+API+Publisher

Comment: Please answer this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64735080/monetization-in-wso2-api-manager-version-2-6-0